# Is there a way to send the switch windows signal without "Alt-Tab"?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, xdotool, xte

I'm trying to bind a switch window button on my mouse into Ubuntu. Currently I'm trying to do it with `xbindkeys` and `xte`, but do this in `.xbindkeysrc` only outputs a <kbd>Tab</kbd> and doesn't switch windows.

**Current `.xbindkeysrc` code:**

```
"'xte' 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Tab' 'keyup Tab' 'keyup Alt_L'"
   b:10
```

I am wondering if there is a different command I could put that would directly give instructions to switch windows.

EDIT: I also tried `xdotool`, here is the code using it:

```
 "xdotool keydown alt key Tab && sleep 1 && xdotool keyup alt"
    b:10
```

It didn't work either.

EDIT2: I tried the `xdotool` one in the command line and it worked. Is there some reason it doesn't work with `xbindkeys`?

Comment: xdotool key alt+Tab works fine on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work. Turns out that I needed to put a pause between `keydown alt` and `key tab`. I also put the `xdotool` code in an `.sh` file so I could modify it without restarting `xbindkeys` every time.

Working `xdotool` code:

```
xdotool keydown alt
sleep .1
xdotool key Tab key alt
```

Answer (score 3):

xte works too, if you use it like

```
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Tab' 'keyup Alt_L'"
  b:10
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with PitaJ's method:
Add the code below into .xbindkeysrc file(replace "user123" to your username and fix the xdotool_Alt_Tab.sh file path to your file path)

```
"/home/user123/xdotool_Alt_Tab.sh"
b:9
```

Note: made xdotool_Alt_Tab.sh executable by

```
 $ chmod +x xdotool_Alt_Tab.sh
```

or right click on that file -> Properties -> Click on the Permission tab -> Check the box of "Allow executing file as program"

I found I needed to press and release that mouse button pretty quick for the Tab key to catch up in time!

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach to emulate a presenter console for presentation software that is missing said functionality.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep .2
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Left
xdotool keydown --clearmodifiers alt
sleep .1
xdotool key Tab
xdotool keyup alt
sleep .2

xdotool key --clearmodifiers Left
sleep .1
xdotool keydown --clearmodifiers alt
sleep .2
xdotool key Tab
xdotool keyup alt
```

Create another one for the right arrow movement and assign them to shortcuts using `xbindkey_config-gtk2` (gui for `xbindkyes`). Then simply have one window open with your slides and another with a pdf document of your notes on separate monitors. Use the assigned keybindings to move to the next slide in both of them with just a small delay.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Tab' 'sleep 1.5' 'keyup Alt_L'"   
  b:2
```

And off course, to install `xte`:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

Since I was looking to keep the switch window open to choose an application from the list myself, this was my final solution. Working pretty well so far.